# React/React Native Global scope

Tags: reactjs, scope, react-native, ecmascript-6, global

Been working on React Native quite some while and would like to get a few things cleared out. What and where are the best way to keep your resources like strings, images etc. At this point I have all my images at the root, but that means that when it gets deeper and deeper I have to:

require('../../../../../../../../..) and can keep on going

I would like to make it global so I can make a import where I need the resources and do something like:

require(images.happyFaceIcon)

The same goes for strings or any method that I dont want to write the path for every time.

Is this possible and how can it been done and last but not least are there any issues by doing this?

Comment: try this.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbjs

Answer (score 0):

first way is you can use `window` object but this is good for simple variables,another way is you can have component folder and each component in own folder and an `index.js` file and you can export all components from index then you just need import you component like this :

```
import {component1,component2,component3} from "components";
```

[this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) is good stracture you can use in `react-native`